# From Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator to List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to feed a method with a collection of type `List<string>` coming from `ApiDescription` objects:

```
public class AddTags : IOperationFilter
{
   public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
   {
      if (context.ApiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methods) == true)
      {
         var test = methods.CustomAttributes
            .Where(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(CustomTag))
            .Select(x => x.NamedArguments.Where(n => n.MemberName.Equals("Tag"))
                          .Select(t => (string)t.TypedValue.Value))
            .ToList();
      }
   }
}
```

The `test` variable returns a collection of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Reflection.CustomAttributeNamedArgument, string>` but I need a result of type `List<string>`.

The custom tag is applied like this in controllers:

```
[CustomTag(Tag = "TEST")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tags = methods.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomTag), true)
                  .OfType<CustomTag>()
                  .Select(attribute => attribute.Tag)
                  .ToList();
```

By the way, `CustomTag` should really be named `CustomTagAttribute`. It will still work as `[CustomTag]`.

Comment: Thanks but does not compile: `'Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.OfType<CustomTag>(IQueryable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'`.

Comment: I assume you are `using System.Linq`?

Comment: yes, I have `using System.Linq` and `using System.Reflection`

Comment: Then this error does not make sense. Did you copy the code 1:1 or did you type it? Can you double check?

Comment: `methods.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomTag), true)` returns an `object[]` not an `Attribute` as in your error message.

Comment: my bad, I typed `GetCustomAttribute` (singular) instead of `GetCustomAttributes`. Thank you, it works fine!

Comment: The expression can be simplified to `var tags = methods.GetCustomAttributes<CustomTag>(true).Select(attribute => attribute.Tag).ToList();`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattributes?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_CustomAttributeExtensions_GetCustomAttributes__1_System_Reflection_MemberInfo_System_Boolean_